# Area differs after dissolve in Geopandas?

Tags: geopandas

I am getting different values for area after dissolving a multipolygon using geopandas. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
temp_file = gpd.read_file("temp.shp")
print('original area: ',sum(temp_file.area))

temp_file['dissolve']=1
dissolved = temp_file.dissolve(by='dissolve')
print ('dissolved area: ',dissolved.area.values)

print (dissolved.columns)
```

I get the following outputs:

```
original area:  13162193.658826955

dissolved area:  [9087595.31178884]

Index(['geometry', 'old_index', 'CALCACRES', 'category', 'farm_id', 'luse_18'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have overlapping geometries in the original GeoDataFrame?

Comment: Thanks! I found the data has some duplicate geometries. Thanks for pointing out the issue!